# How can I pass a value of type enum in a constructor?

Tags: java, enums

I am not too familiar with enum type and I must create a Sport competition class which extends from the class event. It takes in 2 new parameters, one of them being the season of type enum. Not sure how to implement this so that I can choose one of them when initializing the object.

```
package SportCompetition;
import Event.Event;

public class SportCompetition extends Event {
    enum Seasons {SUMMER,FALL,WINTER,SPRING};
    int numberOfActivities;

    public SportCompetition(int year, int month, 
                            int numberOfCities, int numberOfActivities) {
        super(year,month,numberOfCities);
        this.numberOfActivities = numberOfActivities;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like passing any other object in Java... You may want to be more specific about what is causing you trouble.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your `Enum` outside the class. When you have an `Enum` defined you can use it like you use other classes to declare a variable and set it using a constructor.

Try the Below code:

```
public class SportCompetition extends Event {

    int numberOfActivities;
    Season season;

    public SportCompetition(int year, int month, int numberOfCities, int numberOfActivities, Season season) {
        super(year, month, numberOfCities);
        this.numberOfActivities = numberOfActivities;
        this.season = season;
    }
}

enum Season {
    SUMMER, FALL, WINTER, SPRING
}
```

When you create the object of `SportCompetition` create the object like below.

```
SportCompetition sportCompetition = new SportCompetition(2018,1,4,10,Seasons.WINTER);
```

Comment: And when initializing the object, I would just enter one of the 4 seasons as a parameter and it would only accept one of the 4 seasons? I think I understand now, thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you need to pass one of the Seasons as a parameter of the constructor like Seasons.WINTER. I have edited my answer to show how can you create the object by passing the Enum as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You only have problem in passing enum as argument, so I am creating a constructor which accepts only argument as enum for simplicity and you can extend this solution to your actual problem

Creating a `Enum`

```
enum Seasons {
    SUMMER,FALL,WINTER,SPRING
};
```

Now you want to create an object of SportCompetition from the constructor which accepts only one Enum attribute

```
SportCompetition sportCompetition = new SportCompetition(Seasons.SUMMER)
```

Complete code:

```
public class SportCompetition extends Event {
  int numberOfActivities;
  Seasons season;

  public SportCompetition(Seasons season) {
    this.season = season;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SportCompetition sportCompetition = new SportCompetition(Seasons.SPRING);
  }
}
enum Seasons {SUMMER,FALL,WINTER,SPRING};
```

passing Enum `new SportCompetition(Seasons.SUMMER)`

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Season {
    SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER;
    static Season[] Seasons = {Season.SPRING, Season.SUMMER, Season.FALL, Season.WINTER};
    static public Season fromMonth (int m) {
        int idx = ((m + 10) % 12)/3;
        return Seasons[idx];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    System.out.printf ("%2d %2d %s\n", i, ((i + 10) % 12), Season.fromMonth (i));
```

Okay, first, you have to take care - are your months literal values (1==Jan) or indexes (0=Jan)? Second, Seasons don't change on month borders, or do they in finance seasons? So it's just a prove of concept. But if you want to go with this simplified calender concept, using a linear function to map months to Seasons is the way to go.

And naming - the single thing is a Season.WINTER not Informatiker Alfred Winter and not Seasons.Winter. Seasons would be, and is, a Collection of Season.

```
-> for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) System.out.printf ("%2d %2d %s\n", i, ((i + 10) % 12),  Season.fromMonth (i)); 
 0 10 WINTER
 1 11 WINTER
 2  0 SPRING
 3  1 SPRING
 4  2 SPRING
 5  3 SUMMER
 6  4 SUMMER
 7  5 SUMMER
 8  6 FALL
 9  7 FALL
10  8 FALL
11  9 WINTER
12 10 WINTER
13 11 WINTER
14  0 SPRING
15  1 SPRING
16  2 SPRING
17  3 SUMMER
18  4 SUMMER
19  5 SUMMER
20  6 FALL
21  7 FALL
22  8 FALL
23  9 WINTER
```

I guess nobody understands, why in the enum, we have to repeat the name Season in Season.SPRING and so on. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have got the answer but there possibly could be the reason to keep the enum inside the class to achieve separation of concern.

You could use `static enum` and enjoy the architectural benefit of putting enum inside its relevant class itself.

```
package SportCompetition;
import Event.Event;

public class SportCompetition extends Event {
    static enum Season {
     SUMMER,FALL,WINTER,SPRING
    }
    int numberOfActivities;
    Season season;
    public SportCompetition(int year, int month, int numberOfCities, int numberOfActivities, Season season) {
    super(year, month, numberOfCities);
    this.numberOfActivities = numberOfActivities;
    this.season = season;
}
}
```

And create object like below:

```
SportCompetition sportCompetition = new SportCompetition(2018,1,4,10,SportCompetition.Season.WINTER);
```